# html, css: three state button

Tags: html, css, angular

I would like to create three state button in Angular2 using css- yes/none/no without using jQuery. I found [this](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ufct35ys5t) link in some answer on stackoverflow. The point is, that I need to put a few buttons next to each other, and each of them should be independent- every chosen value should be send to component. I've tried to use label implicitly (remove inputs ids), but it doesn't work. Please see full code: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/793ns64j/).

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="toggle_radio">
    <label for="first_toggle">First Button <input type="radio" class="first_toggle" name="toggle_option"></label>
    <label for="second_toggle">Second Button<input type="radio" checked class="second_toggle" name="toggle_option"></label>
    <label for="third_toggle">Third Button <input type="radio" class="third_toggle" name="toggle_option"></label>
    <div class="toggle_option_slider">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to avoid using the jQuery library or JavaScript altogether?

Comment: The best both, but at least jQuery. But I'm quite new and not sure if it's possible